# Optimization - Saving into Database takes too much time ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: optimization, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, jsonserializer, travelport-api

I am working on .NET Core 3.1 with TravelPort API.

I want to store the flight request and flight response into our database. Saving data into database takes too much time.

```
await context.Logs.AddAsync(new Log()
                {
                    Request = JsonSerializer.Serialize(seatMapReq),
                    Response = JsonSerializer.Serialize(res.SeatMapRsp),
                    ReqFileName = reqFileName,
                    ResFileName = resFileName,
                    RequestType = "Air_Seat_Map",
                    Success = true,
                });

await context.SaveChangesAsync();  // in this line API take 5s-6s
```

How can I optimize this?

Comment: Maybe table is too big? Anyway, you have to profile SQL and check execution plan.

Comment: Or the context is long lived and contains a lot of previous additions or tracked entities etc. The shown code should generate a single db `insert` command, so it cannot be optimized. Try isolating the issue by first checking the context change tracker before the `SaveChanges` call - should contain only one entry.